# .htaccess hiding a page with a 404 page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a file or files, on my server that I want to hide temporarily or permanently from users and search engines using `.htaccess` to redirect those pages to a `404` page. This means that any user or search engine robot that attempts to view the pages will instead see a `404` page.

Here are the lines I added to my `.htaccess` file to redirect some files to a `404` page but it doesn’t seem to work:

```
RedirectMatch 404 antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=236
RedirectMatch 404 antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=129
```

Here is the `.htaccess` code:

```
Options  +FollowSymLinks +Indexes +MultiViews

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)bid=2(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=236(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)bid=3(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=129(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/antalya_apartment.php?$ http://turkish-property-world.com/ [L,R=404]
```

Comment: So what does happen when you go to `<your domain>/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=129`?

Comment: strange with or with <your domain> the pages still show up and i get an HTTP Response Header status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK. all my other htaccess RewriteRule work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of query strings in the URL a simple `RedirectMatch` won’t work. Try this instead using `RewriteRule` with `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)bid=2(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=236(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)bid=3(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=129(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/antalya_apartment.php?$ http://your.sites.domain.name.here/ [L,R=404]
```

Note I set a destination of `http://your.sites.domain.name.here/` since—to my knowledge—you can’t really redirect without a destination. But if there is a way of just having it drop to nothing—or the default `404`—without indicating a destination I’d like to know about that.

**EDIT:** Also, does your Apache even parse `.htaccess` rules at all? Is `AllowOveride` set to `All`? Look at [the official Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for more details.

Comment: `(^|&)bid=[23](&|$)` would also help :)

Comment: this. was the sort of rule i was hunting for... but can't get it to work either. i have a RewriteCond non-www redirect to RewriteRule www in and working. even though i write the http://your.sites. as  http://www, thinking it might clash it seems not to be the problem.

Comment: i was hoping to get both the wonderful codes to work but didn't. i quickly tried to check the reason why, if something to do with my .htaccess rules but nothing. even temporary i #the non-www to www rule and tried no luck. i changed ErrorDocument 404 /index.php back to 404.shtml and still no go.

Comment: could be one of the reasons but i know the .htaccess works fine because when i take out or add a RewriteRule, the .htaccess follows. do you think it still has to do with serverside.

Comment: i took everything out of the htaccess, and just left the above rule in and still no go.?

Comment: just got a reply from hosting. 

<Directory "/">
Options +ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -Includes +IncludesNOEXEC +Indexes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Comment: is at very top and not working. do we need to append with the [QSA] (query string append) tag.

Comment: i have stripped down the htaccess as above, and only added your code